# Чтение из файла логов пинга хоста и вывод среднего значения о потерях

Tags: cmd, ping

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Стоит такая задача:
Написать батник, который бы читал построчно файл логов: считал количество строк, в которых есть ответ и в которых нет ответа, а затем посчитал среднее значение. И хорошо бы процент потерь.
Файл логов выглядит следующим образом:

```
Host: 192.168.10.12  
2014-11-08 - 12:08:58 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=125  
2014-11-08 - 12:08:59 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=125  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:01 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=125  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:10 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=125  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:11 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=125  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:12 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:13 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:14 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:28 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:33 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:38 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:43 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:48 Ping timed out.  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:53 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=125  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:54 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=125  
2014-11-08 - 12:09:55 Reply from 192.168.10.12: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=125
```

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: А хоть что-то уже сделано? Открывай документацию по bat-файлам и пиши, в чем сложность?

Comment: Спасибо, уже сделал!

Comment: @Vasya1985, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.